# How to avoid JavaScript def function written inside feature file to be not printed in html reports?

Tags: karate

I need to avoid def date = read('new-date.js') these wrappers to be printed in the report? is there a way?

def date = read('new-date.js')

A report to be generated without these JavaScript statement in test steps?

Comment: Please read the documentation on "Report Verbosity": https://github.com/intuit/karate#report-verbosity

Comment: http://javascriptisnotjava.com/ Take care in spelling JavaScript

Comment: can i also set this globally in configuration * configure report = { showLog: true, showAllSteps: false }?

Comment: @Vindhiyan yes, read the docs: https://github.com/intuit/karate#karate-configure